# Does secondary long running query and primary DDL operation result in blocking of redo thread only if table is participating in long running query?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019

In a SQL AG scenario, if during a long running query on the readable secondary, a DDL operation is performed on primary, then I understand that the redo thread will get blocked until the long running query on the secondary completes.

Does the blocking of redo thread happen only when the DDL operation table is involved in the long running query on secondary? Or does it not matter that whether the DDL operation table is part of the long running query?

Answer (score 1):

> In a SQL AG scenario, if during a long running query on the readable secondary, a DDL operation is performed on primary, then I understand that the redo thread will get blocked until the long running query on the secondary completes.

It only blocks if the query on the secondary has incompatible locks with the DDL. For example, if you add an index to table T1 and a query is only hitting T2, this will not block any redo for T1. This follows the same typical locking and blocking as any other regular query.

> Does the blocking of redo thread happen only when the DDL operation table is involved in the long running query on secondary?

It can happen for other reasons, such as system operations like page splits for forwarded records in heaps, among various other items.

> Or does it not matter that whether the DDL operation table is part of the long running query?

It follows typical locking and blocking scenarios.

Comment: Can you confirm the primary will never get blocked due to any of this?

Comment: That's a very broad statement. Redo itself does not directly block the primary, however secondary and tertiary effects may cause issues on the primary.

Comment: @variable Details matter. Is the replica in the AG setup with a Synchronous or Asynchronous availability mode?

Comment: Synchronous mode

Comment: The commit mode doesn't really affect this, again there are no primary effects but it *can* affect it in other ways.